# Python using *args with default argument

Tags: python

Python newb here.  Suppose you have a function like

```
def myfunc(a = "apple", *args):
    print(a)
    for b in args:
        print(b + "!")
```

How do you pass a set of unnamed arguments to *args without altering the default argument?

What I want to do is

```
myfunc(,"banana", "orange")
```

and get the output

```
apple
banana!
orange!
```

but this doesn't work.

(I'm sure this has been discussed before but all my searching came up empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3 you can do this by changing `a` to a [keyword only argument](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/):

```
>>> def myfunc(*args, a="apple"):
        print(a)
        for b in args:
            print(b + "!")
...         
>>> myfunc("banana", "orange")
apple
banana!
orange!
>>> myfunc("banana", "orange", a="watermelon")
watermelon
banana!
orange!
```

In Python 2 you'll have to do something like this:

```
>>> def myfunc(*args, **kwargs):
        a = kwargs.pop('a', 'apple')
        print a 
        for b in args:
             print b + "!"
```